# Youtube link not supported

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, upload

I have a website in ASP.NET MVC. After page load, I am getting the error below. I have passed the Youtube URL dynamically but am getting an error:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://www.youtube.com/v/g5RM5StrMXY does not permit cross-origin framing
```

My Code:

```
<script>
  function closeVideowindow(k) {
    alert(k);
    var URL = $('#cnad_text_1').val();
    var htm = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src=' + URL + '?rel=0 frameborder="0"    allowfullscreen ></iframe>';

    parent.$('.current').html(htm);
    parent.$('.current').removeClass('current');
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
  }  
</script>

<h1>Upload Video</h1>
  <div class="form_scpop">
    <form action="" method="get" name="sizeform">
      <!-- <frameset>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t090py6b0lM" width="853" height="480"></iframe>
      </frameset >-->
      <h2>Insert a youtube video Link</h2>
      <div class="col2">
        <input id="cnad_text_1"  name="cnad[text_1]" class="input_txt">
      </div>
      <input name="" type="submit" value="Save" class="saveurl"  onclick="closeVideowindow(this)" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you're using a wrong URL, try to use :

> http://www.youtube.com/embed/g5RM5StrMXY

If it still doesn't work, consider loading the video in a `object` rather than in an `iframe` :

```
<object width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/g5RM5StrMXY?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/g5RM5StrMXY?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: @Bigood... this url working i knw but some urls not supported ..what you have to do...

Comment: @DotnetReSource Sorry, I don't understand your sentence?

Comment: @Bigood... Some Youtube vedio links not working..some Vedio urls working

Comment: @DotnetReSource I took the URL of your question `Load denied by X-Frame-Options:` and changed the `/v/` for `embed``, so your original URL clearly didn't work. You might need to transform the URL the user pass by your form to get the ID of the video and then make it look like `http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxx`

Comment: @Bigood.. Exactly right but user can choose from any where for example he choose from youtube how can append 'Embed'user cannot know choose embed..

Comment: @DotnetReSource Please read again my precedent comment : you'd have to transform the user's URL after he passed it through your form

Comment: @Bigwood .. I am split the link..  As of u said i had tried and added the embeded which are not having the word and which are have wil not add but not playing only embeded viedo supporting  i need global like to support to all the url is that possibel if it plz provide me some idea

Comment: @DotnetReSource let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26016/discussion-between-bigood-and-dotnet-resource)